# Ubuntu 12.04.3 - Expanding/Resizing LVM partition upon additional Disk in a Hardware RAID 5

Tags: 12.04, raid, lvm

We have a database server configured as hardware RAID 5 with 3pcs 1TB Disk. Usable is 2TB and partition as follows: `/data` is LVM

```
Filesystem          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              92G  1.6G   86G   2% /
udev                   16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 6.3G  300K  6.3G   1% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                   16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda2             466M   30M  412M   7% /boot
/dev/sda5              46G   52M   44G   1% /home
/dev/mapper/data      1.7T  967G  630G  61% /data
```

Now, if I add one more disk to our RAID 5, usable disk will be 3TB. How can I expand my LVM partition to make use of the additional disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have done the RAID part and you've booted into your system again.

Unmount your /data:

```
umount /data
```

Check your logical volume path:

```
lvdisplay
```

Resize your logical volume to 100% of the available size and perform resizefs:

```
lvresize -l 100% -r /logical/volume/path
```

After that you should be able to mount it again:

```
mount /data
```

Comment: I havent done this yet. Though I was wondering, Can I resize this to more than 2TB? I've been seeing some posting that 2TB is the max.

Comment: Filesystem limits depend on 2 things. The type of filesystem you use and the kernel you run. If you have 2.6 or higher kernel, you most likely have nothing to worry about, since the kernel is usually created with the CONFIG_LBD option enabled (which enables large FS sizes). In order to see the limit of your filesystem check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems

Comment: I have a question here. I hope you can help. http://askubuntu.com/questions/627685/ubuntu-12-04-and-hardware-raid-5-and-lvm

Comment: I checked, the filesystem used is ext4 and kernel is 3.8 - so does that mean that I can expand my LVM /data ext4 up to 1EB as stated in the link you provided.

Comment: Correct (assuming you have a 64-bit OS, which is quite the standard nowadays)